# ¿Como almacenar varias estructuras en otra?

Tags: c++, estructuras

Tengo estas tres estructuras en c++:

```
struct Profesores{
    char nombre[30];
    double ci;
}prof[100];

struct Asignaturas{
    char nombre[30];
    char id[30];
    struct Profesores p_prof;
}asig[100];


struct Alumno{
    char nombre[30];
    double ci;
    struct Asignaturas p_asig;
}alum[100],*p_alum=alum;
```

Y para un proyecto de la universidad nos pidieron que el programa debía preguntar al usuario cuántos alumnos desea registrar, y que para cada alumno preguntara cuantas materias desea registrar, igual para los profesores de la materia, y no encuentro la forma para colocar una especie de arreglos de estructuras anidadas dentro de otra estructura (alumnos).

Ya que es nuestro primer proyecto en C++ hasta ahora el conocimiento que poseo es de condiciones, arreglos, funciones, un poco de punteros (todabia no lo uso muy bien).. entonces ese es mi problemas como almacenar varias estructuras en una sola, pidiendole al usuario cuantas estructuras desea enlazar.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de compartir mi sugerencia contigo, me gustaría sugerirte otras correcciones. En C++ la palabra clave `struct` no forma parte del tipo, los `struct` ya son un tipo *per se*, por ello no es necesario anteponer dicha palabra clave para definir instancias de esos datos, tus definiciones de tipos podrían quedar así:

```
struct Profesores{
    char nombre[30];
    double ci;
};

struct Asignaturas{
    char nombre[30];
    char id[30];
    Profesores p_prof;
};

struct Alumno{
    char nombre[30];
    double ci;
    Asignaturas p_asig;
};
```

Así, el tipo `Asignaturas` almacena **una** instancia de el tipo `Profesores` mientras que el tipo el tipo `Alumno` almacena **una** instancia de el tipo `Asignaturas`.

Si quieres almacenar texto, lo más conveniente es usar `std::string`, que te permitirá almacenar textos de longitud arbitraria (nada de limitarlo a 29 caracteres), tus definiciones de tipos podrían quedar así:

```
struct Profesores{
    std::string nombre;
    double ci;
};

struct Asignaturas{
    std::string nombre;
    std::string id;
    Profesores p_prof;
};

struct Alumno{
    std::string nombre;
    double ci;
    Asignaturas p_asig;
};
```

Por otro lado, tu nomenclatura es muy confusa, usas el plural para referirte a conceptos únicos; ¡no hay concordancia de número! es como si me dijeras "¿*Te gusta mi coche**s**?, ¡es aquel**los** de ahí*!". En general deberías usar el singular para tipos y el plural para colecciones, tus definiciones de tipos podrían quedar así:

```
struct Profesor{
    std::string nombre;
    double ci;
};

struct Asignatura{
    std::string nombre;
    std::string id;
    Profesor p_prof;
};

struct Alumno{
    std::string nombre;
    double ci;
    Asignatura p_asig;
};
```

Ahora veamos tus enunciados:

> Para cada alumno preguntara cuantas materias desea registrar, igual para los profesores.

Si lo entiendo bien, profesores y alumnos son exáctamente iguales (contienen materias) así que a priori no es necesario una clase diferente:

```
struct Asignatura {
    std::string nombre;
    std::string id;
};

struct Persona {
    std::string nombre;
    std::string id;
    std::vector<Asignatura> asignaturas;
};
```

El tipo `Persona` puede ser un alumno o un profesor, si necesitas diferenciarlos puedes usar dos tipos distintos (como hacías antes) o añadirles un enumerado que internamente los distinga:

```
enum Tipo {
    Alumno,
    Profesor,
};

struct Persona {
    Tipo tipo;
    std::string nombre;
    std::string id;
    std::vector<Asignatura> asignaturas;
};
```

Para cumplir con la premisa de que tanto alumnos como profesores deben registrar materias, he añadido un `std::vector` de `Asignatura`, para registrar elementos podrías hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
Persona crear_persona()
{
    Tipo t;
    std::string nombre, id;

    // Preguntar si es alumno o profesor
    // ...

    // Preguntar el nombre
    // ...

    // Preguntar el id
    // ...

    return {t, nombre, id};
}
```

Y para añadir materias, también podrías crear una función auxiliar:

```
Asignatura crear_asignatura()
{
    std::string nombre, id;

    // Preguntar el nombre
    // ...

    // Preguntar el id
    // ...

    return {nombre, id};
}
```

Con estas funciones auxiliares tu código podría quedar así:

```
int main() {
    int asignaturas;

    Persona p = crear_persona();
    std::cout << "¿Cuantas asignaturas tiene asignadas " << p.nombre << "?\n";
    std::cin >> asignaturas;

    for (int asignatura = 0; asignatura != asignaturas; ++asignatura) {
        p.asignaturas.push_back(crear_asignatura());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por las correcciones, voy a probar lo que me dijistes, lo que pasa es que esa es la version ''corta'' del proyecto porque los alumnos y profesores deben separarse los alumnos tienen que tener 6 datos mas y los profesores 2 mas. otra cosa anoche encontre "la solucion" pero no se si es correcto usarlo struct struct
    `struct Asignaturas p_asig[100]`
con eso le dejo almacenar varias estructuras asignatura en la estructura alumnno